# visual basic increment on cell update

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel

Currently trying to take each cell update and store in a cell that is basically A55 plus one row each update. So start with A55 then next update A56 then A57 so on forever on each update. Current code is stuck at cell 55 though:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("U13")
    Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 55
    If Not Intersect(target, Range("U13")) Is Nothing Then
   Cells(Counter, "A").value = target
    End If
      Counter = Counter + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Each time this is run, it will start with `Counter=55` and the increment, `Counter=Counter+1` will not carry over to the next execution.

Comment: You could create a helper cell to store your counter value and increment and update that cell's value before you exit.  If you use a named range for the cell, such as `MyCounter`, then `Counter=Range("MyCounter").Value` and `Set Range("MyCounter").Value=Counter+1`

Comment: Would I still use Counter inside the target?

Comment: Do you mind making an answer so I can vote for it and see it in full please

Comment: If Counter were to be declared at a global level, and initialized at 55.  Then you could increment it within this sub.

Comment: when i try to put     Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = 55 at global i get invalid outside procedure

Comment: @ReyJuna range of object worksheet failed

Comment: I posted it as an answer.  Also, the range object problem was my using `Set Range("MyCounter").Value=` when it should have been `Range("MyCounter").Value=`.  I corrected that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count the rows in column A

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim target As Range, LstRw As Long

    Set target = Range("U13")
    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If LstRw < 55 Then LstRw = 55

    If Not Intersect(target, Range("U13")) Is Nothing Then
        Cells(LstRw, "A").Value = target
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @James `xlUp` - the letter `l`, not the number `1`

Comment: Okay this still did not work. nothing happens. At least in my code a55 updated.

Comment: Check if you have other cells filled in below A55, maybe there are some way down.

Comment: That worked! How can I delete all on a button click clear for example, or delete all when it is loaded.

Comment: `Range("A55:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Clear` , although you will have to make sure there is something in A55 or it will clear cells above it. Maybe just use `range("A55:A1048576").clear` then there would never be a problem

Comment: tried to do this Range("A55:A1048576").Clear
Range("B55:B1048576").Clear
Range("C55:C1048576").Clear
Range("D55:D1048576").Clear
Range("E55:E1048576").Clear
Range("F55:F1048576").Clear

Comment: Just for future proofing I would change `range("A55:A1048576").clear` to `range("A55:A" & rows.count).clear`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when you want to run init(), you'll have to pick an event.  But each time you run Worksheet_Calculate() after that it will increment.

```
Public Counter As Integer

Sub Init()
    Counter = 55
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("U13")

    If Not Intersect(target, Range("U13")) Is Nothing Then
    Sheet1.Cells(Counter, "A").Value = target
    End If
    Counter = Counter + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: how will I run something, new to vb

Comment: I am not sure how to get this working in context of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper cell to store your counter value and increment and update that cell's value before you exit.

If you use a named range for the cell, such as `MyCounter`, then modify your code to this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Counter As Integer

Counter = Range("MyCounter").Value

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U13")) Is Nothing Then
    Cells(Counter, 1).Value = Target
    Range("MyCounter").Value = Counter + 1
End If

End Sub
```

I changed the event type to `Worksheet_Change`.  `Worksheet_Calculate` doesn't allow you to pass the Target as Range.

The approach you were using with `Set target = Range("U13")` and then `Intersect(target, Range("U13"))` means that `target` always equals `Range("U13")` and therefore this will always execute when anything causes a calculate event, not just a change to cell U13.  Didn't sound like that was what you wanted.

Also, the increment counter needs to be inside the `IF` statement or it will be incremented on every event, not just the ones you are checking for.

Here is a screen shot

[image: Increment on cell update using helper cell]

Note: This shows the results after 5 updates.

Cell Y1 is named "MyCounter" and you would initialize it to 55.  Then each time you change the value of cell U13, it will put that value into the row that MyCounter is pointing to and then increment MyCounter.

I would recommend that you put your helper cell on another sheet instead of the way that I did it in the example, but if you do then update the code to include the sheet name in the range reference, such as `Counter = Sheets("HelperSheet").Range("MyCounter").Value`.  Hope that helps.